# I can't call my method from class to form

Tags: c#, xml

I have one problem I can't fix:

I want my class `admin` to contain this method:

```
public void OpretSpejder()
{
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Snavn_txt.Text)))
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Senavn_txt.Text)))
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sa_txt.Text)))
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Scpr_txt.Text)))
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(@"Spejder.xml");

                var nodeCount = 0;
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Spejder.xml"))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                            reader.Name == "Spejder")
                        {
                            nodeCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                nodeCount++;

                XmlElement Spejder = doc.CreateElement("Spejder");
                Spejder.SetAttribute("ID", nodeCount.ToString());

                XmlNode Navn = doc.CreateElement("Navn");
                Navn.InnerText = Snavn_txt.Text;
                Spejder.AppendChild(Navn);

                XmlNode Efternavn = doc.CreateElement("Efternavn");
                Efternavn.InnerText = Senavn_txt.Text;
                Spejder.AppendChild(Efternavn);

                XmlNode Alder = doc.CreateElement("Alder");
                Alder.InnerText = Sa_txt.Text;
                Spejder.AppendChild(Alder);

                XmlNode Cpr = doc.CreateElement("Cpr");
                Cpr.InnerText = Scpr_txt.Text;
                Spejder.AppendChild(Cpr);

                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Spejder);
                doc.Save(@"Spejder.xml");

                Snavn_txt.Text = String.Empty;
                Senavn_txt.Text = String.Empty;
                Sa_txt.Text = String.Empty;
                Scpr_txt.Text = String.Empty;

                MessageBox.Show("Spejder Oprettet");
            }
        }
```

and I want the method to be executed in a button click in another form. But it cannot recognize my textboxes..  that's the only problem.

For each instance it just says: The name 'Scpr_txt' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Post the code from the button click. It doesn't matter to us what your  `OpretSpejder` method is doing. You should simply be able to do `myAdminInstance.OpretSpejder()`

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OpretSpejder();
}

this is the button code

Comment: Did you declare `Scpr_txt` anywhere?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty What kind of syntax is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't couple the presentation layer class with my classes. Instead of accessing a TextBox directly you should pass the text to a method.

```
public void OpretSpejder(string Snavn_txt, string Sa_txt, string Scpr_txt )
{
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Senavn_txt)))
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sa_txt)))
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Scpr_txt)))
            {
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

the first way is to add parameters to your `OpretSpejder` function.

the second way is to make a public `Form2` in your `Form1` like this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
```

then you can use:

```
f2.textbox1.text
f2.textbox2.text
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to tell you that it doesn't recognize where the TextBox exists.  You could pass a reference to the textbox into the method.